# iBeacon - changing the UUID - Major/Minor values on a iBeacon without provided SDK

Tags: bluetooth, sdk, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, uuid

I have purchased a number of these iBeacons: http://www.ebay.com/itm/272156171343

All of the 3 beacons that I have purchased from the above link com with the excact same UUID values.

Unfortunately I cannot find any SDK to change their UUID - major and minor values. I've been looking to find ways to establish a 2 way communication with the beacons without luck so far.

Anyone aware of a way to differentiate my beacons UUID from each other?

Thanks!

Comment: The listing mentions AT commands, so it probably exposes some BLE service, possibly only for a short duration when it is first powered up.  If you have an iOS device I can suggest the LightBlue app for a BLE scanner or maybe look at the radius networks rad beacon dot; a similar product with better support

Comment: This seems to be the link to the documentation; http://cnlearn.linksprite.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/ibeacon%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E8%AF%B4%E6%98%8E%E6%96%87%E6%A1%A3.pdf good luck